# Anchor inheritance

Tags: inheritance, anchor

I created a  and gave it color: red;
I want all the elements inside the div to be red so I wrote:
div *{color: inherit}

Now I created inside the  an  element, and I wanted it to be the default color(blue), so I wrote:
color: initial;
Turned out that it does not bring it back to be blue, but makes it black, I don't understand why! the initial supposed to applies the initial (or default) value of a property to an element!

So, I have two questions:
Why the initial don't make it blue?
How can I get this  back to be as default?
Thank's for the help.

```css
div{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    color: red;
    background-color: wheat;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

div *{
    color: inherit;
}

div a{
    color: initial;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Index</title>
<style> 

</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>



<div class="main">
  <p>this is paragraph</p>
  <a href="javascript:void()">Anchor inside the div</a>
</div>
  <a href="javascript:void()">Usual anchor</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So why not `inherit`?

Comment: The inherit just keep it red.

Comment: Try `unset` then. Initial doesn't mean "bring back to default" actually. I think you misunderstood the definition of "default".

Comment: unset also keep it red

Answer (score 0):

Just define the initial color of the link first:

```
a:link {
    color: blue;
}
```

Then the `color: initial` will work as intended.